# Generating wind direction raster using its U and V components in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, raster

I have two raster layers representing the U and V components of a vector wind. I could generate the magnitude raster by applying `(u*u+v*v)` in Map Algebra in ArcGIS.

Now I need to generate the direction raster with the following function:

```
if(u > 0 && v > 0,( atan(u/v) + 180),if(u < 0 && v < 0,(atan(u/v) + 0),if(u > 0 && v < 0,( atan(u/v) + 360), if(u < 0 && v > 0,( atan(u/v)+270)))))
```

but I don't know how to apply it in ArcGIS. Any help please?

Answer (score 8):

Use [ATan2](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/ATan2/009z000000n6000000/), as in

```
ATan2(-v, -u) * (180 / 3.14159265)
```

Note that

1. The wind direction vector is assumed to be (u, v).
2. Because the construction in the question appears to compute the *reverse* direction, the direction is reversed by negating both components.
3. The second component of (-u, -v) is the *first* argument to `ATan2` (the help page does not explain this crucial point).
4. The result is in radians, which is converted to degrees via the multiplication.

---

Because this result will lie in the range (-180, 180] and the question appears to want a value in the range [0, 360), a modulus function can be used to change the range.  Unfortunately, the [Mod](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Mod/009z00000094000000/) function in ArcGIS only works on integers.  For full precision we need to implement the modulus ourselves using an alternative such as [Int](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Int/009z0000008z000000/).  A streamlined pair of formulas is

```
x = ATan2(-v, -u) / (2*3.14159265) + 1
(x - Int(x)) * 360
```

Here, `x` represents the bearing of (-u,-v) as a fraction of a whole circle.  The addition of 1 guarantees the fraction will lie between 1/2 and 3/2.  The expression `x - Int(x)` extracts the fractional part of that number.

For example, with u=-1 and v=1 (a direction pointing towards the northwest) we find that ATan2(-v, -u) = ATan2(-1, 1) = -0.7853982.  Dividing by 2*Pi (=2*3.14159265 in single precision) yields -0.125.  The addition of 1 increases that to 0.875 (of the way around the circle).  The operation of subtracting its integer part leaves it unchanged at 0.875, which in degrees is 0.875 * 360 = 315.  That is the direction *counterclockwise relative to east.*  To obtain the bearing *clockwise relative to north* simply reverse the roles of `u` and `v` in the formula.

---

Because adding or subtracting a half circle to any bearing reverses its direction, an equivalent but more efficient expression to use is

```
(ATan2(v, u) / (2*3.14159265) + 0.5) * 360
```

The additive constant 0.5 arises as the difference between 1 and 0.5 (the half circle).  When you read this formula, think like this:

> ATan2 finds the bearing of (u,v) (*via* `ATan2(v, u)`) counterclockwise relative to East.  That's converted to a fraction of the whole circle (`/ (2*3.14159264)`), which is then spun around by a half-circle to reverse it and, incidentally, make the result non-negative (`+ 0.5`).  Finally the whole thing is converted to degrees (`* 360`).

Comment: Can you add how to do this if you had integers and used the Mod function. So of you rant an INT on the 180 to -180 and used Mod.

Comment: @Ifyoudonotknow-justGIS I believe all that information is already in this post.

Comment: a remarkably elegant solution. I did it manually from https://www.eol.ucar.edu/content/wind-direction-quick-reference and followed  directions above. I can confirm this answer works and is a very elegant approach.

Comment: I don't know if I understand well which one should I use in the end, so what I need to do is to use this expression: (ATan2(v, u) / (2*3.14159265) + 0.5) * 360

Is that correct?

Comment: @carolina Because the expressions I gave are mathematically equivalent, the choice is yours.  More efficient is usually better.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `if()`, use `Con()` (conditional) in Raster Calculator.

The logical if/else structure is essentially the same, but the syntax is different (also, single `&` to combine conditions):

```
Con(u > 0 & v > 0, (atan(u/v) + 180), Con(u < 0 & v < 0, (atan(u/v) + 0), Con(u > 0 & v < 0, (atan(u/v) + 360), Con(u < 0 & v > 0, (atan(u/v) + 270)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Arcgis, the formula is calculated in a specific and different way than in R, Matlab or Excel...etc.

The exact formula for the wind direction in Arcgis is :
ATan2( v , u)* (180 / 3.14159265359)

I do not agree with the other formulas presented, as they give wrong wind directions.

Comment: I am trying the formula you have suggested. So, which orientation do we need to select for plotting the wind direction vectors? Is it arithmetic orientation or geographic orientation in ArcMap?